# 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out in Jasmine 2.3.1

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, gulp, karma-runner

I'm running karma test cases through gulp as below:

```
gulp.task('unit-test-karma', function () {
    return gulp.src(filePaths.libraryPaths.concat(filePaths.codePathsVerbose.concat(filePaths.testPaths).concat(filePaths.htmlPaths).concat(filePaths.jadePaths)))
        //.pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: notify.onError(function(error) { console.log(error.message); return "Karma Error"; }) }))
        .pipe(karma({
            configFile: './karma.conf.js',
            action: 'run', // watch
            singleRun: true,
            reporters: [ 'dots' ]
        }));
});
```

When I run with action as `run`, IE 11 throws below error.

```
IE 11.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out
  at C:/BbCAT-WebDI/BbCAT-Web/BbCAT-Angular/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:938
```

But if run the same with action as `watch` then all test case executing successfully in chrome, IE and firefox.

After reading some post, It seems there is some issue with $http service call but not able to find from where exactly the problem is!

Comment: Are you using `$httpBackend` in your unit tests to stub out your `$http` service calls? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: Yes. that's why I'm wondering because the directive function which I'm testing have 4 http calls and all are simulated with fake response then why it's throwing this error!

Comment: Have you eliminated the possibility that a different test is causing the error to be thrown, i.e. make sure the test you suspect is the only test being run?

Comment: Also, does the directive function call any other services that are not mocked, that may trigger an http request? Be sure to mock everything...even $exceptionHandler could be causing your problem.

Comment: @ShaunScovil Thanks for your help but I already make sure all of these cases.

Comment: Can you show the test and code being tested?

Comment: Show us some code please!

Comment: I added code. Please have a look

Comment: Is your it block inside of a describe block?

Comment: yes. I didn't paste full code. I verified that this is the block which is having problem as I tried running with `xit` for this block and it's working fine.

Comment: Your code is a big mess. That's not how test cases should look like. Please refactor it and use //given//when//then pattern, also test only one with one unit case, otherwise it'll be a huge, complex and unmaintanable test case. Also it's not normal that you have 10+ $httpBackend mocks. Try to clear it and then we can help figuring out what is the issue.

Comment: When I run into weird problems that seem to not make any sense, I try to run it with a different browsers. Chrome or FF might give you some more specific, and actionable error messages or at least some more clues to triangulate the cause.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this error, but it was because I had a `describe` function without an `it` function inside.

Incorrect

```
describe('helpDocsDirective', function () {   
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

Correct

```
describe('helpDocsDirective', function () {
    it("should return true", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment:  Thanks for saying this. Can't believe I got caught by it.

Answer (score 2):

Could you have nested a couple of tests that should be separated, or have multiple async calls resolving in the same test case?

I produced this same error, but it was of my own doing. I had two async tests inside of one it(). As soon as either of the promises resolved, the test ended. The other promise resolution was orphaned.

Consider these snippets. Assume that the function under test responds correctly as called.

Note: I have left out the error paths from the then() for purposes of illustrating the issue more clearly.

This construction fails. When either of the promises return and done() is fired, the second one now fails with the "'expect' was used when there was no current spec..." error.

```
describe( "delay", function(){
    var calculator = new Calculator();

    it( "delays execution - add and subtract", function(done){
        delay( 1000, calculator, 'add', [ 10, 5 ] )
            .then(function(result){
                expect(result).toEqual( 15 );
                done();  // <---- as soon as this runs, test is over
            });

        delay( 500, calculator, 'subtract', [ 9, 5 ] )
            .then(function(result){
                expect(result).toEqual( 4 );
                done(); // <---- as soon as this runs, test is over
            });
    });

} );
```

This is the correct way to write the tests. Each promise is encapsulated in its own test.

```
describe( "delay", function(){
    var calculator = new Calculator();

    it( "delays execution - add", function(done){
        delay( 1000, calculator, 'add', [ 10, 5 ] )
            .then(function(result){
                expect(result).toEqual( 15 );
                done(); // <--- this is now the only resolution for  this test
            });
    });

    it( "delays execution - subtract", function(done){
        delay( 500, calculator, 'subtract', [ 9, 5 ] )
            .then(function(result){
                expect(result).toEqual( 4 );
                done(); // <--- this is now the only resolution for  this test
            });
    });

} );
```

As I don't yet have enough reputation to comment, I'm putting my plea here. :-)

Could you mark this answer as correct if this turns out to be your problem?

Comment: I was getting same error because I was testing asynchronous code, `done()` does the trick

Answer (score 1):

This is a very real problem, I am currently experiencing it too. I think there is a core bug here. I have very well encapsulated tests. they are small (at most 3 lines each)

I have a main describe section with 2 nested describes
first describe has 8 it() functions
second has 3it() functions.

i.e

```
describe("main", ()=>{
    describe("1st", ()=>{
        //here are 8 it() definitions
    })
    describe("2nd", ()=>{
        //here are 3 it() definitions
    })
})
```

Now when I remove a single it() definition from either describe, the issue disappears. Alternatively, if I add a 3rd describe(), the issue disappears.

This is an issue in jasmine - either they are not reporting an error correctly, or there is something horribly wrong. Alternatively it may be karma trying to be smart by running multiple tests simultaneously.. Either way, this problem is real and it's got nothing to do with messy code.

Perhaps it has to do with the underlying unit being tested - my function is recursive  (though my test cases don't dive deep).

karma-jasmine@0.3.8

jasmine-core@2.4.1

karma@0.13.22

phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.7

karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.0

Comment: Further, if I instead of adding a 3rd describe, add a 9th it() definition, the problem goes away again. - it's certainly racing somewhere...

Comment: Please try changing to chrome launcher and re running. This will provide two things. 1 phantomjs gives terrible errors.  2. Hopefully it is phantomjs. Because chrome runs headless

Comment: There is a known issue with more than 10 tests in a describe. Newer versions of jasmine solves this

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue here, it turn out that I had a test with setTimeout. Cleared that and all good!

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding a done inside your catch() or try() just after your expect() call;
like this

```
it('should return a Promise that resolves', (done) => {
        let promise = promiseFunction();
        promise.then(response => {
          expect(true).toBe(true);
          done();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Also had this error message in Jasmine 3.5 - it threw me more than it should have, as it was talking about async and I have some jquery in project from someone else.

It was just a syntax issue in setting up the test ... my original

```
it("should ...")
  expect(thing).toBe(whatever);
})
```

Versus the working ...

```
it("should ...", function(){
  expect(thing).toBe(whatever);
})
```